# Avoiding GCM throttling when syncing data across devices

Tags: android, rest, google-cloud-messaging, synchronization

I am using GCM to sync data across all user devices. When there is new data, generated by one of the devices, the server(RESTful API) sends a push to the rest, and each of them downloads the new data and updates the UI. The problem is that Google throttles my notifications when there are lots of changes(like 40 per minute = 40 pushed per minute per device) and the devices stop receiving new messages for a day or two. I read a lot about the topic and found that I should set time to live to 0 and delay while idle to false, but throttling still occurs.

So my question is, is it possible to disable GCM throttling and how could you recommend me to implement the whole sync process with RESTful backend?

Comment: Are you using a collapse key?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot disable throttling. It is a function performed by GCM and one of its uses is to preserve device battery life. In your case, 40 pushed messages per minute doesn't sound very efficient - you may want to consider whether you should compound those messages into fewer messages.

Or, use collapse key to collapse all these messages that are in transit, as suggested by @ianhanniballake.